# CHECKBOX Cell Event in GWT is not working in updated chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-app-engine, gwt

Hi I have used DATA Grid Table in which i have a CheckBox Cell and SetFieldUpdater on it which is working fine on Older version of chrome and not working on latest version of chrome. I have used GWT SDK 2.6.1 and Appengine 1.9.6. My code is as follows

```
checkColumn=new Column<Invoice, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell()) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(Invoice object) {
            return object.getRecordSelect();
        }
    };

    checkColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Invoice, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, Invoice object, Boolean value) {
            object.setRecordSelect(value);
            table.redrawRow(index);             
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions????

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the new Chrome that you don't see in the old version?

Comment: Actually i am using two events on my table. 1: CHECKBOXCELL EVENT and 2: SelectionChangeEventHandler for row.. In Updated chrome 2nd event executes instead of checkboxCell when clicked on check box ....?

Answer (score 2):

it may be browser compatibility issue - meta tag might help you

For more details follow below url -

What's the difference if  exists or not?